# Get 100 palindrome numbers

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm new at scripting and I have this assignment, which is to find 100 [*palindrome*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) numbers with the following algorithm:

1. Get a two-digit random number (greater than 10)
2. Reverse the number
3. Sum the number and its reverse
4. If the result of the sum is a palindrome number, print it.
   Otherwise, back to step 2

---

For example:

- Starting number: 75
- Reverse is 57
- The sum is 75+57 = 132

As 132 is not a palindrome number, back to step 2:

- Reverse is 321
- 132 + 321 = 363
- 363 is a palindrome number. Print it to stdout!

And so on until it prints 100 of these numbers.

---

This is what I have so far:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

CONT=0
while [ $CONT -lt 100 ] 
do
    NUM= $RANDOM
    while [ $SUM -ne $SUMINV ] 
    do

        echo $NUM > file.txt
        INV= rev file.txt
        SUM= `expr[ $NUM + $INV ]`
        echo $SUM > file2.txt
        SUMINV= rev file2.txt
        NUM= $SUM
    done
    echo $NUM
    CONT=`expr $CONT + 1`
done
```

Looking for solutions and help with this script!

Comment: I had errors running your script so have cleared some syntax and convention issues in the code. See if it works now. If it is assignment, I would suggest you fight it out on your own.

Comment: @Ketan please never, _ever_ fix syntax errors in the question. That should be done in an answer. If you fix the errors, the question itself can end up making no sense since we won't be able to understand what's wrong with the OP's script. In any case, your edit still left syntax errors which makes it even less useful :)

Comment: @terdon Ok, got it.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand firstly you need to receive two-digit number which

- greater 10 and less 100
- not divided by 10 (no 20;30; etc)
- isn't palindrom (no 22;33; etc)

So you can reach it by

```
while :
do
  a=$[$RANDOM%10]
  b=$[$RANDOM%10]
  if [ $a -ne $b -a $a -ne 0 -a $b -ne 0 ]
  then
    NUM="$a$b"
    RNUM="$b$a"
    break
  fi
done
```

Next step to check the sum of number and its revers

```
while :
do
  NUM=$[$NUM+$RNUM]
  RNUM=$(printf "%d" $NUM | rev)
  if [ $NUM -eq $RNUM ]
  then
    echo $NUM
    break
  fi
done
```

Comment: The OP wants palindromes ("If the result of the sum is a palindrome number, print it. Otherwise, back to step 2") and as far as I can tell, they have no restriction on whether the number is divisible by 10. That's a clever trick to get the two digit numbers though.

Comment: @terdon As for me there is no sense in numbers divisible by 10 same as palindroms already even it make the easy way to receive 2-digit number by `$RANDOM%100`

Answer (score 1):

There were various syntax errors in your original script. For example `foo= bar` is wrong, spaces are important in bash. You need `foo=bar`. Also, to get the output of a command, you can't do `foo=command`, you need to enclose the command in backticks, or, better `foo=$(command)`. Here's a working version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
CONT=0

## This array will hold the numbers we've seen
## uncomment this line for unique numbers
#declare -a seen;
while [ "$CONT" -lt 100 ] 
do
    ## Get a random number
    NUM=$RANDOM
    ## Make sure it is < 100
    let "NUM %= 100"
    ## Make sure the number is more than 10
    while [ "$NUM" -le 10 ]
    do
        NUM=$((NUM+1))
    done
    ## In case the addition made it longer than two digits
    NUM="${NUM:0:2}"
    ## Make sure the number does not end in 0
    ## If it does, we will get an error when
    ## attempting to add it. Bash doesn't
    ## like leading 0s. 
    [[ $NUM =~ 0$ ]] && let NUM++
    ## Sum the number and its reverse
    SUM=$((NUM+$(rev <<<$NUM)));

    ## Is this a palindrome?
    if [ "$SUM" = "$(rev <<<$SUM)" ]
    then
        ## You did not say if you wanted 100 different
        ## numbers. If so, uncomment these lines
        #let seen[$SUM]++
        ## If this number has not been seen before
        #if [ "${seen[$SUM]}" -eq 1 ]
        #   then
        ## print it
        echo $SUM
        ## increment the counter
        let CONT++
        #fi
    fi
done
```

Note that as is, the script will repeat numbers. To get unique numbers uncomment the lines as described in the comments of the script.

Answer (score 1):

This one is fun. I like this question. I wrote the following function to perform the task and it does the job.

```
palindromes() (
rev()   while getopts : o "-$1" ||
        ! r="${2#"${2%%[1-9]*}"}"
        do set -- "$1" "$OPTARG$2"
        done
rand()  { : & : "$(($1=$!))"; }

[ "$1" -gt 10 ] || exit
n=$1; set --
while OPTIND=1; rev "$n"
        case "$#.$n.$r"                              in
        (100.*) ! printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$@" ;;
        (*.$r.$n) set -- "$@" "$n"; rand n           ;;
        (*)       n=$((${n#-}+${r%-}))               ;;
esac; do :; done
)
```

There are a couple of things that are noteworthy about this. In the first place, `getopts` is used to reverse the number. The primary function of `getopts` is to parse short options that may or may not be all strung together - and it therefore makes a convenient tool for looping over every byte in a string.

I don't much like the `$RAND` function of the `bash` shell, but probably it is more conservative than is my `rand()` function which just backgrounds a no-op task and assigns its defunct PID to whatever varname is stored in its first argument. Pretty cheap, that, I'll admit.

The `case` construct can easily evaluate all facets of your assignment in a simple test. I do:

```
case "$#.$n.$r" in 
(100*) all done; printf %s\\n "$@";; 
(*$r.$n) palindrome; set -- "$@" "$n";;
(*) no luck; $n+$r; go again;;
esac
```

I had a lot of difficulty with this at first. At first I was doing stuff like:

```
(*$r.$n) set -- ...; n=$((n+1))
```

That was a *bad* idea. The runaway addition immediately grew the numbers to sizes that the just the digit count was enough to blow away any likelihood of ever finding a palindrome. I messed around with `date +%S` but I figured if I was going to run another process anyway, I might as well just use its PID. And that process, in that case, might as well just be a null-op. Anyway, the PID range is small enough to reign in the runaway factor pretty much every time, it seems.

For example, I'll run this right now and paste in the results:

```
palindromes 76
```

#### OUTPUT

```
484     29292   49294   69296   89298
215512  50605   90609   446644  886688
123321  52625   92629   468864  663787366
134431  54645   94649   881585188       7667585634365857667
145541  23432   43434   63436   83438
147741  24442   44444   64446   84448
158851  25452   45454   65456   85458
169961  13231   46464   66466   86468
49985258994     27472   47474   67476   87478
14355341        28482   48484   68486   88488
395593  29492   49494   69496   89498
219912  121121  11244211        441144  881188
125521  165561  15522551        463364  7365409856589045637
136631  211112  17858768886785871       485584  893974888888479398
147741  23632   43634   63636   83638
149941  24642   44644   64646   84648
523325  25652   45654   65656   85658
567765  13331   46664   66666   86668
2358532 27672   47674   67676   87678
2236322 28682   48684   68686   88688
```

There are probably some dupes in there - it happens, apparently. Not many. I dunno if that's a problem for you or not, but this is just an example of how it might be done.

One last note - running this in `dash` is far faster than it is in `bash`; though the difference seems to be just a second or so. In any case, *if you do* use `dash` you'll need to alter the `rev()` `set -- "$1"` line to `set -- "${1#?}".`

I just realized there is a two-digit requirement - though my suspicion is that this specific rule is an attempt to keep the assignment from getting too hard. Anyway, getting only a subset of a string is very easy to do. In fact, it is what I do with `r=` when I:

```
r="${2#"${2%%[1-9]*}"}"
```

...which always assigns `r` a value that does not begin with a zero.

Here's a version of `rand()` that always assigns a two-digit number to `$1`:

```
rand() { : & set -- "$1" "$!" "$(($!%100))"
         : "$(($1=($3>10?$3:${#2}$3)))"
}
```

You can apply the same logic to `bash`'s `$RAND` of course. The `$((var=(value)?(assign if true):(assign if false)))"` ternary operator will work with nearly any integer set. Here I either assign it the modulo of 100 *(basically a percentile)* if that value is greater than ten, else I assign that as the second of two digits where the first is a count of the digits in `$!`.

Run that way and its results are a little less exciting:

```
333     66      484     1111    4884
77      88      99      121     121
363     484     77      4884    44044
88      99      121     121     363
484     1111    4884    88      8813200023188
99      121     121     363     484
1111    4884    44044   8813200023188   99
44      55      66      77      44
99      121     121     363     484
424     11      33      44      55
66      77      88      99      121
22      33      22      55      66
77      88      99      121     121
33      44      55      33      77
88      99      121     121     363
44      55      66      77      44
99      121     121     363     484
55      66      77      88      99
55      121     363     484     1111
66      77      88      99      121
```